# R Plotly rangeselector autoselect "1W"

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Right now i got a graph in plotly made in R with the following rangeselector:

```
                xaxis = list(
                rangeselector = list(
                    buttons = list(
                        list(
                            count = 7,
                            label = "1W",
                            step = "day",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 1,
                            label = "1M",
                            step = "month",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 3,
                            label = "3M",
                            step = "month",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 6,
                            label = "6M",
                            step = "month",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 1,
                            label = "1J",
                            step = "year",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 2,
                            label = "2J",
                            step = "year",
                            stepmode = "todate"))),

                #rangeslider = list(type = "date")
                FALSE
            ),
```

[image: Current Rangeselector]

I'm trying to autoselect "1W" but i can't find the code to do that in the Plotly Documentation.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Opened an [issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1836) on **plotly**'s GitHub page and linked your post. Let's see if something can be done here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to choose default value, but if you `add range =` with the same date as the prefered range it will have the same result.

Here is the full code if the latest date is today. If not you can just do something like `range = max(as.Date(df$date))-7, max(as.Date(df$date)))` if your dataframe is called "df" and the dates are in column "Date".

```
xaxis = list(
  range = c(Sys.Date()-7, Sys.Date()),
  rangeselector = list(
    buttons = list(
      list(
        count = 7,
        label = "1W",
        step = "day",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 1,
        label = "1M",
        step = "month",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 3,
        label = "3M",
        step = "month",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 6,
        label = "6M",
        step = "month",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 1,
        label = "1J",
        step = "year",
        stepmode = "backward"),
      list(
        count = 2,
        label = "2J",
        step = "year",
        stepmode = "todate"))),

  #rangeslider = list(type = "date")
  FALSE
),
```